# How to fix a DataTemplate Grid's size and center visible content?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, grid, resize

It's pretty hard to formulate this question without writing a novel...

I have a DataTemplate in a Style (applied to a TabItem if that matters), which provides a Grid containing two TextBlocks in a vertical fashion.

I'd like to be able to have my **Grid staying the same size** (height, in this case) and the **first TextBlock centered** (here, vertically) when **the second TextBlock is collapsed** (or hidden, I don't care).

[image]
[image]

How can I achieve that?

Here's what I have so far (the Text values are placeholders here, they're supposed to be bindings):

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}" x:Key="FlatTabControl">
    <Style.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
            <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="TOP/MIDDLE"/>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Foreground="Green" Text="BOTTOM/COLLAPSED"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}" >
        <Style.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid Width="150" Height="30">
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="TOP/MIDDLE" />
                                <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Foreground="Green" Text="asdsad"  Height="Auto" x:Name="TextTwo"/>
                            </Grid>
                            <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                                <Trigger SourceName="TextTwo" Property="Text"  Value="">
                                    <Setter TargetName="TextTwo"  Property="Height" Value="0"/>
                                </Trigger>
                            </DataTemplate.Triggers>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </Style.Resources>
    </Style>
```

Comment: That's the idea, but I'm not set on my global font size, so I can't just set `Height="30"`.